# CATextLayer + AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool - not respecting word wrapping?

Tags: ios, macos, avfoundation, core-animation

I have a `CATextLayer` containing an attributed string. I've set the `textLayer.isWrapped = true`.

The layer and word wrapping works great when previewed in a `AVPlayer`.

However when I try to export it using  `AVMutableVideoComposition.animationTool` to render it over a video:

`let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
 videoComposition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(
                          postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, 
                          in: parentLayer)`

The word wrapping does not seem to be respected. I've also tried to rasterize the layer first:

`textLayer.shouldRasterize = true`

but seems to have no effect.

Help!